# But, who will watch the watchdog?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In computer software, we have a "watchdog" process, which makes sure that the other software is running correctly and has not crashed.

Which, of course, leads to an obvious question, and I will like to know how to ask in Latin `"but, who will watch the watchdog?"` (Juvenal seems to have forgotten that one :-)

Comment: Welcome!  I've edited your question to ask for a Latin idiom equivalent to the English one, as I imagine you are more interested in what Latin speakers might say to express this idea, rather than a direct translation of the phrase.

Comment: Now I'm noticing your mention of Juvenal, which suggests that you are familiar with *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?*  Are you actually asking here for a translation of "watchdog"?

Comment: Sort of. But I can Google for that. Woudl it still have the same "feel"? I _think_ so, but am not not confident enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would advise using Juvenal's phrase without revision:

> Sed quis custodiet ipsos / custodes? ([Satire VI](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/juvenal/6.shtml), 347-48)

As Lewis & Short remarks in its entry for [custos](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcustos), the term can be used alone to refer to (watch)dogs. Here is one example from Virgil:

> Occupat Aeneas aditum **custode sepulto**,
>   evaditque celer ripam inremeabilis undae. (*Aeneid*, VI, 424-25)
>
> *Aeneas through hell's portal moved, **while sleep
>
>   Its warder buried**; then he fled that shore
>
>   Of Stygian stream, whence travellers ne'er return.*

Note that the whole trope is that the verb and noun align, so you would lose the flavor of the passage by reworking it to something like *Quis custodiet ipsos canes?*

If, however, you specifically want to emphasize that this guard is *not* a human, then I suppose it is possible to insert some kind of irreverent revision to get this across. (I say "irreverent" fully conscious of the fact that we are modifying a decidedly unscrupulous satire :)

> Quis custodiet ipsos canes custodientes?

Note that this revision uses the present participle of *custodio*: I am not aware of any adjective derived from this word that would work better.